# Edit Google Forms settings using Google Forms API

Tags: rest, google-forms

I am generating a lot of Google Forms using the Google Forms API and I'm using `batchUpdate` to set title, description, questions etc. **However, I'm unable to find anything about setting the settings of the form**:

[image: Google Forms settings tab]

I couldn't find anything about it on the internet nor in the Google Forms API documentation.
Any ideas on how I could set these settings?

Answer (score 0):

Google Forms API might not provide direct methods to update form settings using the batchUpdate method. The API primarily focuses on updating form elements like titles, descriptions, and questions.

To update form settings programmatically, you might need to resort to using Google Apps Script or other automation methods. Google Apps Script allows you to manipulate Google Forms settings using the FormApp service.
This is an example of Google app script

```
function updateFormSettings() {
  // Replace 'FORM_ID' with the actual ID of your Google Form
  var form = FormApp.openById('FORM_ID');

  // Access form settings
  var formSettings = form.getSettings();

  // Modify form settings
  formSettings.setTitle('New Form Title');
  formSettings.setDescription('New Form Description');
  formSettings.setLimitOneResponsePerUser(true); // Set to true or false based on your requirement

  // Commit the changes
  formSettings.saveAndClose();
}
```

To use Google Apps Script, open your Google Form, go to "Extensions" > "Apps Script," and paste the code into the script editor. Then, run the updateFormSettings function. Make sure to replace 'FORM_ID' with the actual ID of your Google Form.